# Run node script on linux user login

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, authentication

I have a js script that parses an rss feed and displays any updates and displays them using bash's notify-send. I'd like to start the script when I log in using the graphical user interface. I'm on fedora (Using Gnome). I've tried several things with no success including adding it to my systemd unit files so it can start as a service, adding it to /etc/.profile, .bashrc...
I know the script itself works, and most tests have been with a simple "notify-send 'hello' 'world'" instead of the script, just to take away possible problems. 
Any ideas how I can start the script when I log in?

A little more information: I need to start /usr/bin/node myfile.js when the user logs in through the gui. I'm not really worried about he command itself, I just need to get to the point where I can run any bash command when the user logs in. So far, I've added

```
notify-send "hello" "world"
```

to several scripts that should run on login including .xsession, systemd unit files, .bashrc, .profile, /etc/.profile and several other files hoping when I logged in, I would see a notification with hello world. Nothing has worked so far. I have varified that notify-send works in general on my system.

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/150311/how-do-you-start-a-program-after-x-has-started/

Comment: 1. There is no answer to that forum post. 2. Those options do not appear to work in my situation.

Comment: 1. That question (not a forum) has 4 upvoted answers. 2. We don't know enough about your set up in order to debug it.